# How to find count of element in a vector of pair

Tags: c++, stl

I have a vector of pair as below

```
vector<pair<string, vector<string>> v;
```

My datasets are like

```
'10', vector1
'10', vector2
'10', vector3
'20', vector4
'20', vector5
```

I want the output as count of 10 - 3 and count of 20 - 2. May I know how to perform count algorithm with vector of pair.

I tried with

```
std::count(v.begin(), v.end(), iterator->first)
```

but resulted in compilation error.

Comment: Are the elements sorted on the first member of the pair: the string?

Comment: in terms of the compilation error, i guess over here it's counting the pair in the vector v instead of the string in the pair

Answer (score 6):

How about making a simple histogram:

```
std::map<std::string, unsigned int> h;

for (auto const & x : v)
{
    ++h[x.first];
}

for (auto const & p : h)
{
    std::cout << p.first << " occurs " << p.second << " times.\n";
}
```

Comment: This is definitely a better option than the rubbish I came up with.

Comment: @juanchopanza Or not.  It depends what the actual problem is.  If he only wants one count, your solution is best.  If he wants all of them, the he should use this one.

Comment: @JamesKanze I re-read the question, and I think they want all the counts. My solution might still work well for small vectors, but it seems silly to traverse the whole vector for each count.